# Add callback to function that is called from inside arr map method

Tags: reactjs

I need to map over an array in my state and assign the returned value to another property in my state.
I then need to call a function using the value of the updated property as a parameter, wait for this function to complete and then move on to the next item in my array map method before repeating the process.

The problem is that I think my function is being run before the state has been updated through each iteration of my arr.map method.

I think I need to utilise the componentDidUpdate() method before running my function, but I am not sure how to implement that in this scenario.

Simpler to explain through code example, see below (edited for simplicity):

```
state = {
  a: [ {name: 'some string'}, {name: 'some string'}..... ],
  b: '' // empty string
}

// when button is clicked, this function is run
myFunc() {
  this.state.a.map( (item) => { 
    this.setState({
      b: item.name
    })
  mySecondFunc()// perform next part of the loop
  })
}

mySecondFunc() {
  alert( this.state.b )
}
```

The alert in mySecondFunc() does not return anything, it is not being updated before the function is run.
What I need to happen is that the map will get the first item from my states 'a' array, assign it to state 'b' and run mySecondFunc().
I need to wait for state to be updated, before calling mySecondFunc, and then wait for mySecondFunc() to end its function before the map gets the next item from my state's 'a' array and calls mySecondFunc again.

This is the part that I cannot figure out.

Comment: that state inside `map` might cause this error *Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.*

Comment: Hi Junius. I am not receiving that error, and it's not a problem, the array i am mapping over only has 20 items - the problem I am having is that the state is not updating before mySecondFunc has been called, run and completed - 20 times

Comment: Can you use the `setState` callback to run `mySecondFunc` after the state update? `this.setState({ b: item.name }, () => mySecondFunc() )`

Comment: Hi Seanulus, when I do this it seems to map through the whole array, return the last item's value and then run the callback mySecondFunc, it doesn't return arr[0] value, perform callback, then return arr[1] value, perform callback and so on....

Comment: What are you using `state.b` for? The fact that you are constantly overwriting it leads me to believe there may be a better approach than storing it in your sate.

Comment: Hi smashed-potatoes, I am using chartjs to display data of sports clubs. state.b is just the name of the sports club, I am then using that name value (assigned to state.b) to loop through json data and retrieve games played by said club.

Comment: In that case, are you able to pass the name directly to your second function rather than using your state? e.g.: `mySecondFunc(item.name)`

Comment: Hi smashed-potatoes, possibly, with some refactoring of code, I will try this technique

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
state = {
  a: [ {name: 'some string'}, {name: 'some string'}..... ],
  b: '' // empty string
}

// when button is clicked, this function is run
myFunc(){
 this.state.a.map(async(item) => { 
   await this.setState({
      b: item.name
    },async () => {
        await mySecondFunc()// perform next part of the loop
      })
  })
}

mySecondFunc() {
   alert( this.state.b )
}

//OR 

myFunc(){
 this.state.a.map(async(item) => { 
    await mySecondFunc(item)
  })
}

mySecondFunc(item) {
  alert( item )
}
```

Comment: Hi samad, I have tried to implement your first option but it does not alter my result.
I will need to refactor some more code in order to implement your second option, so will get back to you

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood from the problem description is that the goal here is to pass b's value sequentially to mySecondFunc . According to my understanding of the problem, I have modified your code :

```
myFunc() {

  this.state.a.map( (item) => {

        this.setState( (prevState) => {


            const modifiedName = item.name;

            this.mySecondFunc(modifiedName);

            return {
                b: modifiedName
            }

        });


    });


}
mySecondFunc(name) {
        alert( name );
}
```

Comment: Hi Sudip, thanks for your response. I have also tried this previously, it maps through the whole array, returns last item and then calls the mySecondFunc()

Comment: @Jonny I have modified my code. I overlooked the last part of the problem description.